# How to understand coroutine cancellation is cooperative

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Kotlin, [coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) cancellation is cooperative. How should I understand it?

[Link to Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html).

Comment: What is unclear for you?

Comment: "Coroutine cancellation is cooperative. A coroutine code has to cooperate to be cancellable. All the suspending functions in kotlinx.coroutines are cancellable. They check for cancellation of coroutine and throw CancellationException when cancelled. However, if a coroutine is working in a computation and does not check for cancellation, then it cannot be cancelled,"

Comment: Cooperative cancelation is described well here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Java background, you may be familiar with the thread interruption mechanism. Any thread can call `thread.interrupt()` and the receiving thread will get a signal in the form of a Boolean `isInterrupted` flag becoming true. The receiving thread may check the flag at any time with `currentThread.isInterrupted()` — or it may ignore it completely. That's why this mechanism is said to be cooperative.

Kotlin's coroutine cancellation mechanism is an exact replica of this: you have a `coroutineContext.isActive` flag that you (or a function you call) may check.

In both cases some well-known functions, for example `Thread.sleep()` in Java and `delay()` in Kotlin, check this flag and throw an `InterruptedException` and `CancellationException`, respectively. These methods/functions are said to be "interruptible" / "cancellable".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure whether I understand your question, but maybe this helps:

Coroutines are usually executed within the same thread you start them with. You can use different dispatchers, but they are designed to work when being started from the same thread. There's no extra scheduling happening.
You can compare this with scheduling mechanisms in an OS. Coroutines behave similar like to cooperative scheduling. You find similar concepts in many frameworks and languages to deal with async operations. Ruby for example has fibers which behave similar.

Basically this means that if a coroutine is hogging on your CPU in a busy loop, you cannot cancel it (unless you kill the whole process). Instead, your coroutines has to regularly check for cancellation and also add waits/delays/yields so that other coroutines can work.

This also defines on when coroutines are helpful the most: when running in a single-threaded-context, it doesn't help to use co-routines for local-only calculations. I used them mostly for processing async calls like interactions with databases or web servers.

This article also has some explanations on how coroutines work - maybe it helps you with any additional questions: https://antonioleiva.com/coroutines/